# How to remove cache of system internal buffers after i/o operations?

Tags: android, android-ndk, sd-card

I'm building a benchmark project between android device and sd-cards to track performance changes between different types of sd-cards.

In my benchmark I'm using many io methods, and both logical and physical access to the sd-card.
Sometimes I control the size of the internal buffer (with `setnvbuf()`)

Between each file read/write I would like to clear the system's cache or internal buffer.
What is the best way to manage this?

My project is partially native, using ndk, so I can use a c/cpp approach if needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bench marking file systems is hard. There are various levels of caching. When you make i/o operations Linux (kernel) will cache your data and it is hard to manage that cache, see this [cyanogenmod wiki page](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/wiki/SDCardSpeedTests) for example. In fact you shouldn't ever rely on such mechanism, but instead use longer running tests to see sdcards' performance - which in general brick them (I'm serious).

Checking long lived projects doing file system benchmarks is also a very good idea, for example [iozone](http://www.iozone.org/).

Comment: non of those links help me with the cache.. Do you have some reference to the caching levels and how to control them?

Comment: No, point is your benchmark app / algorithm needs to function without controlling caches.

Comment: If for every read I'm creating new file. Does it bypass the caching difficulty?

Comment: If it doesn't cache what you write.